# File issues with threading in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc

I have a  tomcat server and i have a controller which writes in to a file, the data coming in the request. SO my doubt is whether multiple threads within the server can write into the same file at the same time and cause issues?

My requirement is that all requests appends data to the same file. I am not using any threading from my end.

My code is as follows:

```
File file = new File(fileName); 
try { 
    if(!file.exists()) { 
        file.createNewFile();    
    }
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
    BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferWriter.write(IOUtils.toString(inputStream));
    bufferWriter.flush(); 
    bufferWriter.close(); 
}
```

Comment: are you opening the file on each request or all share the same writer?

Comment: Right now i am opening the file each time . My code is as follows -File file = new File(fileName);
  try {
   if(!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();   
   }    
   InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();   
   FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName,true);   
   BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
   bufferWriter.write(IOUtils.toString(inputStream));
   bufferWriter.flush();
   bufferWriter.close();
  }

Answer (score 2):

There is the standard solution for such issue.

You have to create `singleton` class, which will be shared between all threads.

This `singleton` will have some `BlockingQueue` (e.g. `LinkedBlockingQueue`) in which all threads will put their messages for writing into single file.

This `singleton` by it self also will be the `Thread` and inside its `run()` method it will constantly `take` values from `queue` and sequentially write it into needed file.

Comment: It would be better to store an instance of the object (which is supposed to write to the file) in the `ServletContext` rather than creating a singleton. This is the way to go in Java web applications when you need an object to be accessible by all other components.

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is that all requests appends data to the same file

Doing a task for each request (like logging or in your case, appending text to a file) can be best implemented using a filter (`javax.servlet.Filter`). You don't have to create a singleton manually then and you can turn a filter on or off whenever you need its functionality or not.

However, you still need to synchronize the concurrent access to your file. As Andremoniy pointed out, you can do this using an own Thread, so that your filter does not block the request/response.

**EDIT**

One thing about the shared object used to write to the file: It is better to store an instance of this object in the `javax.servlet.ServletContext` rather than creating a singleton object. This is the standard way to go if you need to have an object accessible by all other components in a Java web application using servlets.

Comment: So wont the tomcat server take care of synchronizing threads?

Comment: @user1643001 Certainly not. It goes to great lengths to ensure they can all run concurrently. Otherwise it wouldn't work very well, and you wouldn't use it.

Comment: Can we use Synchronised block?

Comment: @user1643001 yes, you can. Basically, you can use any synchronization method you know in Java.